# Why do Srivastava et al. claim that "the best" theoretical regularization technique involves all possible network parameter settings?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, posterior, overfitting, dropout

In the [original paper on Dropout](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf) by Srivastava, Hinton, Krizhevsky et al. (2014), the authors make this claim in the introduction:

> With unlimited computation, the best way to "regularize" a fixed-size model is to average the predictions of all possible settings of the paramaters, weighting each setting by its posterior probability given the training data.

Here is how I understand that statement so far:

- For a single neural net architecture and hyperparameter configuration, the set of all possible trained weight configurations is $Μ$.
- Each individual model $μ ∈ M$ has a Bayesian posterior probability $p_μ$ given the training data $D$.
- For a given example $x ∈ D$, the prediction of any individual model is $f_μ(x)$
- An optimally regularized system makes a prediction equal to the sum of all individual predictions, but weighted by the model's posterior

  $f(x) = \sum p_μ \cdot f_μ(x)$

Please correct me if I've misinterpreted there.

**Why is that "the best way" to regularize a particular network, given unlimited computational power?**

To me, trained weights’ distribution of posteriors is not clearly connected to overfitting and regularization.  But I trust these authors are correct, so I would really appreciate some help seeing how those are connected.

Comment: the weighting they suggest is $f(x) = \int_w p(W=w \mid X=x) f_W(x) dW$. Note $p(W=w \mid X=x)$ the posterior usually is computed via bayes rule $p(W=w \mid X=x) = \frac{p(X \mid W) p(W)}{p(X)}$. You can see that $p(W)$ is the prior on the parameters. That is by definition the regularizer. Furthermore you are using the updated prior on the model to predict, so in this sense, is there anything better you could considered?! This feels nearly by definition the best thing to do. Essentially prior == regularization plus the data is already included so excellent, what else did you want?

Comment: note that not overfitting means that we bias our model somehow to good generalizing solution, which is what the prior does. To not under fit however, we need the data, which is what the posterior does. Essentially with the given prior that is probably the best one can do, unless one had access cheap and good cross validation data and then  you just test all possible prior (and then the posterior given data) which essentially allows you to just check all priors (with cross validation).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on weighting and for the explanation, @Pinocchio.  Can you explain what you mean by "You can see that $p(W)$ is the prior on the parameters. That is by definition the regularizer."  I see how $p(W)$ is the prior on parameters, but I don't yet understand how the posterior is the regularizer.  I must be missing something obvious!

Comment: Forget the full bayesian perspective for a second. Now just recall the traditional regularization framework for kernels. Like $\cal E_{\lambda}(f) = \cal E(f) + \lambda \| f \|^2_{\cal H} = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} L(f(x^{(i)}),y^{(i)}) + \lambda \| w \|^2_{2}$. This is by definition an example of Tikhonov regularization. If you remember the first term is minimizing the empirical loss which corresponds to minimizing the likelihood $p(X|W)$ and the second term is choosing a $w$ with small norm which corresponds to $p(W)$. Its equivalent to the MAP. As in $argmax_{W \in \cal H} P(X|W)P(W)$

Comment: then to have an example where they are fully equivalent the standard exercise is everything is Guassian both prior and likelihood. That gives regularized least squares (plus inserting some logs to have things break up as sums). In the end the point that one needs a prior to guarantee some type of generalization, in the model class or the algorithm itself has to be doing the regularization implicitly. Usually regularization means a collection of techniques/models that avoid overfitting and give generalization or good generalization. It doesn't even have to be rigorous as in deep learning.

Comment: To help you decipher my comments and how it address your question the reason the posterior "regularizes" its because $\log P(W|X) \alpha \log P(X|W)  + \log P(W) $ and whatever procedure you use to choose models will explicitly use your prior, at least your prior on $W$, which regularizes (your biasing your prediction to some model class with your prior). Essentially that gives stability to the way you choose your predictor. So the short answer is prior's regularize, though its not always necessary as I said algorithms itself can regularize or model classes.

Comment: An example of an algorithm that regularizes by itself is early stopping which doesn't usually require a prior on W explicitly (and probably SGD in deep learning). If your search is already restricted in some class thats also usually regularizing. As I said regularizing is a word that just means "any technique that helps generalize". In some cases we know what causes it rigorously in others as in deep learning we can only make good guesses (=infer) based of empirical evidence and thinking.

Comment: Thanks again, @Pinocchio.  That's all helpful.  This statement is the most helpful: "_whatever procedure you use to choose models will explicitly use your prior, at least your prior on $W$, which regularizes (your biasing your prediction to some model class with your prior). Essentially that gives stability to the way you choose your predictor._"

Comment: @Pinocchio I think that these comments could be collected together to make a fine answer (which I would up-vote!).